# Flask - Obtain Input from HTML page and pass input into a function in another Python file

Tags: python, html, flask

I am attempting to gain user input from a html file and pass it into a function that is located in another python file within the same directory.

The user should input their username and password into the html webpage and the inputs will be passed into another a python file to run numerous validation functions.

Some help or guidance would be much appreciated :)

Thank you

form.html file

```
<form action="{{ url_for("gfg")}}" method="post">
<label for="username">username:</label>
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username">
<label for="password">password:</label>
<input type="text" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password">
<button type="submit">Login</button>
```

app.py file

```
# importing Flask and other modules
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

# Flask constructor
app = Flask(__name__)



# A decorator used to tell the application
# which URL is associated function
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def gfg():
   if request.method == "POST":
      # getting input with name = fname in HTML form
      username = request.form.get("username")
      # getting input with name = lname in HTML form
      password = request.form.get("password")

      return username + password
   return render_template("form.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

main python file (where functions are located)

```
def main():
    
    username = app.gfg()[0]
    password = app.gfg()[1]
    TestLogin(username, password)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: error message]

Comment: Please paste the full traceback error here. and don't post images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the request context.

> RuntimeError: Working outside of request context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
> needed an active HTTP request. Consult the documentation on testing
> for information about how to avoid this problem.

```
[...]
with app.test_request_context(
        '/url/', data={'format': 'short'}):
    username = app.gfg()[0]
    password = app.gfg()[1]
    TestLogin(username, password)
    [...]
```

You can have a look at the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/reqcontext/#manually-push-a-context)

Comment: so would i need to make the username and password a global variable?

Comment: I don't think so there is a need to make username and password global. but If you want to access them globally, you can use sessions. in the gfg function you can use `session["user"] = username` and `session["pass"] = password`. Now you can access variables using `session["user"]` and `session["pass"]`

Comment: from flask import app, request, render_template, Flask, session

from Validate.validation import TestPrerequisite

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'hjshjhdjah kjshkjdhjs'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session["MSISDN"] = request.form.get('MSISDN')
        session["password"] = request.form.get('password')

    return render_template("form.html")



TestLogin(session["MSISDN"], session["password"])

Comment: session don't work inside with `app.app_context()`, as I see. you can use them outside with block. define both of them to variables, `username = session["user"]  password = session["pass"]`. then in the with block use `TestLogin(username, password)`.